# Creating class object based on xml file, withouth using xml parsing library

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

So i am having this homewrok that i need to create an XML Parser, without using any parsing library (such as TinyXML, Xerces and so on...). A task is to use Object-oriented programming, so basically i need to store each element as a object of some class, so that I can edit it after that through that class and return the new values to the xml file. (for example if there are elements with the same "id" attributes, i need to change them... or get all children elements of an element with certain id...) Below is what i've written as class, but after that i am not sure how to read the file and store the information in objects of the class.
I looked up in many places for answers but if i found anything it would be beyond my level, and i could barely understood it. I'd be really grateful if someone helps me :) 
Thanks in advance

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;

const int MAX_TEXT = 500, MAX_ATR = 10, MAX_NAME = 20;

class Attribute {
private:
    char* attr_name;
    char* attr_value;
public:
    char const* get_attrName() { return attr_name; }
    char const* get_attrValue() { return attr_value; }
    Attribute(char const* n = "<No Attribute>", char const* v = "<Empty>");
    //Attribute(Attribute const& a);

    void set_attrName(char const* n);
    void set_attrValue(char const* v);
};

class Element {
private:
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    char* id;
    char text_content[MAX_TEXT];
    Attribute attr[MAX_ATR];
    Element* children_array;

public:
    Element(char const* ID = "<No ID>", Element* children = nullptr);
    char const* get_elemId() { return id; }
    Attribute get_Attr(int a) { return attr[a]; }     
    void set_elemID(char const* id_name);
};
```

Comment: Read the file byte by byte, and on each byte decide what to do with it (buffer it, or store it somewhere, either as element's or attribute's name or value).

Comment: Honestly, this looks more like *graduate thesis* than homework ...

Comment: Start by defining parsing functions for the lowest-level elements (`parseOpeningBracket`, `parseTagName`, `parseAttribute`) and combine these in higher-level functions (`parseOpeningTag`, `parseBody`, `parseClosingTag`) until you have a `parseXml`.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o A simple XML parser should be something anyone can bang out in a day or two.

Comment: Please have a read through this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: SiKing, what I asked for is just a small part of the project I have..... never have I asked someone to do my job, but help me wth a problem I cant solve :) thanks to the others :)